# Converting str into datetime and fetching all data from db

Tags: sqlite, discord, discord.py

I tried to make a tasks.loop() for checking a muted user that needs to be unmuted, but there's a few problem while doing this, i can't use fetchall() for some reason because it will gives me this error

```
toremove = muteremove[2]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If i use fetchone() maybe it only fetch 1 user every 10 secs, i mean how to fetch all the data every 10 sec to unmute a user?
Also if i use fetchone() it will say that it `can't convert str into datetime.datetime object`, how can i fix this?

```
    @tasks.loop(seconds=10)
    async def muted_user_check(self):
        self.cur.execute(f"SELECT userId, guildId, expiredAt FROM mutedlist")
        muteremove = self.cur.fetchall()
        if muteremove is None:
            print("No user to unmute :D")
        if muteremove is not None:
            toremove = muteremove[2]
            timenow = datetime.utcnow()
            if timenow > toremove:
                self.cur.execute(f"DELETE FROM mutedlist WHERE guildId = {muteremove[1]} and userId = {muteremove[0]}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert a string into a datetime object, you can use the `strptime()` method:

```py
from datetime import datetime

def convert(date, format):
    return datetime.strptime(date, format)

[input] convert('22/08/2020', '%d/%m/%Y')
[output] 2020-08-22 00:00:00
```

The output will be a datetime object that you can format with the `strftime()` method like so:

```py
#Example
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now() #now will be a datetime object
now.strftime('%d/%m/%Y - %H:%M:%S') # DD/MM/YYYY - hours:minutes:seconds
```

Here's a list of some formats:

- %A → Weekday (%a for abreviations and %w for numbers)
- %-d → day of the mount (1, 2, 3, 4, ...)
- %B → Mounth name (%b for abreviations and %-m for numbers)
- %I → Hour (12h clock)
- %p → AM or PM
- %H → Hour (24h clock)
- %M → Minutes
- %S → Seconds
- %f → Microseconds
- %c → Local date and time representation

---

Using your code, it would be:

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=10)
async def muted_user_check(self):
    self.cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM mutedlist")
    mute_list = self.cur.fetchall()
    if not mute_list:
        print("No user to unmute :D")
    else:
        timeNow = datetime.utcnow()
        for mute in mute_list:
            muteExpire = datetime.strptime(mute[3], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            if timeNow > muteExpire :
                self.cur.execute(f"DELETE FROM mutedlist WHERE guildId=? AND userId=?", (mute[0], mute[1]))
```

Comment: So if i wanted to format the datetime from database which is string, i need to do `muteremove = self.cur.fetchone()` and `convert('muteremove', '%d/%m/%Y')` ?

Comment: Haven't work, but the formatting things was working pretty well. Can i contact you on discord :/

Comment: My nickname is Mr_Spaar#0523